# Arrow for div bubble-box

Tags: javascript, css

I have this  that is hidden until click button. How can I add an arrow-down icon coming down from the Advançed button as an indication that the box comes out after pressing that button?

There should be a kind of triangle or some shape that indicates that the box comes from there. Something like a speech bubble

Something like this:
[image]

```js
function toggleAdvanced() {
  var button = document.getElementById("advanced_filter_button");
  var target = document.getElementById('advanced_filter_container');
  if (target.classList.contains("block--closed")) {
    target.classList.remove("block--closed");
        target.style.height = (target.offsetHeight + target.scrollHeight) + "px";
    button.innerText = "Avançat ▲";
  } else {
    target.classList.add("block--closed");
        target.style.height = 0;
    button.innerText = "Avançat ▼";
  }
}
```

```css
.searchbar_borderbottom {
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -50vw;
  height: 2px;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: #D9D9D9;
  margin-top: 5px !important;
}

.search_bar_container {
margin-top: 25px !important;
}

.buttons_filter_bar_search .search-button {
padding: 8px;
line-height: 1.4em;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 1px;
cursor: pointer;
color: #fff;
background-color: #249359;
border-color: #249359;
border-radius: 5px;
font-size: 12px !important;
font-weight: 550 !important;
margin-right: 5px !important;
}

.buttons_filter_bar_reset .reset-button {
padding: 8px;
line-height: 1.4em;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 1px;
cursor: pointer;
color: #fff;
border-radius: 5px;
font-size: 12px !important;
font-weight: 550 !important;
width: 35px !important;
}

.buttons_filter_bar_reset .reset-button .iconm-filter {
color: #fff;
font-size: 12px !important;
margin-left: -5px !important;
}

.buttons_filter_bar_reset .reset-button .iconm-close {
color: #fff;
font-size: 14px !important;
position: absolute !important;
margin-left: -2px !important;
margin-top: 5px !important;
}

.searcher-header__block label {
font-weight: bolder !important;
margin-right: 8px !important;
font-size: 14px !important;
}

.filter_container_temporada label {
font-weight: bolder !important;
margin-right: 8px !important;
font-size: 14px !important;
}

.filter_container_mes label {
font-weight: bolder !important;
margin-right: 8px !important;
font-size: 14px !important;
}

.defaults_filter_bar>div {
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.searcher-header__block--invisible {
    display: none;
}

#advanced_filter_container {
    background-color: #dedede;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height 0.2s ease;
    width: fit-content;
}
    #advanced_filter_container.block--closed {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 0;
    }

.advanced-search-bar:after{

}

.advanced-search-bar {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#advanced_filter_button {
background-color: transparent !important;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding: 8px;
line-height: 1.4em;
cursor: pointer;
color: #55555e;
font-size: 13px !important;
font-weight: 550 !important;
}

#advanced_filter_container>div {
margin-right: 15px;
}

#filtro_mes, #filtro_isla, #filtro_temporada, #filtro_modalidad {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none !important;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 3px;
  font-size: 14px !important;
  background-color: #f2f1f1 !important;
}

#filtro_title {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 1px;
  font-size: 14px !important;
  width: 225px !important;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .search_bar_container,
  .defaults_filter_bar,
  .filter_container_temporada,
  .filter_container_mes,
  .buttons_filter_bar{
   display: flex !important;
   align-items: center;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

}


@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .search_bar_container,
  .defaults_filter_bar,
  .filter_container_temporada,
  .filter_container_mes,
  .buttons_filter_bar{
    display: flex !important;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="search_bar_container">
<div class="search_bar_container_left">
<div class="defaults_filter_bar">
            <!-- Year filter -->
    <div class="filter_container_temporada">
        <label for="temporada">Temporada</label>
        <select id="filtro_temporada" class="form-control">
            <option value="all">Totes</option>
        <option value="2022">2022</option><option value="2021">2021</option></select>
    </div>
  <!-- Month filter -->
  <div class="filter_container_mes">
        <label for="mes">Mes</label>
        <select id="filtro_mes" class="form-control">
            <option value="all">Tots</option>
            <option value="1">Gener</option>
            <option value="2">Febrer</option>
            <option value="3">Març</option>
            <option value="4">Abril</option>
            <option value="5">Maig</option>
            <option value="6">Juny</option>
            <option value="7">Juliol</option>
            <option value="8">Agost</option>
            <option value="9">Setembre</option>
            <option value="10">Octubre</option>
            <option value="11">Novembre</option>
            <option value="12">Desembre</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="search_bar_container_right">
<!-- Buttons -->
        <div class="buttons_filter_bar">
                        <div class="advanced-button_filter_bar_search">
<button title="Mostrar filtres de cerca avançats" class="advanced-button" id="advanced_filter_button" onclick="toggleAdvanced()">Avançat ▼</button>
</div>
            <div class="buttons_filter_bar_search">
                <button title="Cercar competició" class="search-button">Cercar</button>
            </div>
                <div class="buttons_filter_bar_reset">
                <button title="Netejar els filtres" class="reset-button"><span class="iconm-filter"></span><span class="iconm-close"></span></button>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="advanced_filter_container" class="advanced-search-bar block--closed">
    <!-- Island filter -->
        <div class="searcher-header__block">
            <label for="isla">Illa</label>
            <select id="filtro_isla" class='form-control'>
                <option value="all">Totes</option>
                <option value="mallorca">Mallorca</option>
                <option value="menorca">Menorca</option>
                <option value="eivissa">Eivissa</option>
                <option value="formentera">Formentera</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Type filter -->
        <div class="searcher-header__block">
            <label for="modalitat">Modalitat</label>
            <select id="filtro_modalidad" class='form-control'>
                <option value="all">Totes</option>
                <option value="pista">Pista</option>
                <option value="cros">Cros</option>
                <option value="ruta">Ruta</option>
                <option value="trail">Trail</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    
    <!-- Name filter -->
    <div class="advanced_filter_container_search_box">
        <input id="filtro_title" type="text" placeholder="Cercar per nom de la competició">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here's some code by MarkBoots doing the hard work for you [Codepen: Speech Bubbles](https://codepen.io/MarkBoots/pen/RwLPXgJ?editors=1100)

Comment: Thanks, I need for the concrete above code.